# Max execution time exceeded when setting set_time_limit(300);

Tags: php, mysql, apache, timeout

I'be been monitoring the system for a while and we get frequently but at random

> Fatal error:  Maximum execution time
>   of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   preprocess.php on line 3.

The file looks like this:

```
<?
session_start();
set_time_limit(300);
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
@ini_set('session.bug_compat_warn','off');// php version installed on the server has a compatibility bug
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: Your hosting provider does not let you change the time limit it seems.

Comment: Won't work in php safe mode. Check your `phpinfo()` output.

Comment: It does work most of the times. And the provider let me to change the setting, it's a dedicated server, we can change anything we want. No safe mode.

Comment: Perhaps a third party script is resetting the time limit.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file for max_execution_time and try changing it in there

Comment: Not a good idea to change the value globally, when you only need it for one script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_time_limt()` OR  `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` for this.
You can visit [this](http://newprograminglogics.blogspot.in/2012/04/extend-maximum-execution-time-of-php.html) blog for a clear description of using `set_time_limit()`

Answer (score -1):

What happens when you use 0 as the time limit?  And as someone else mentioned,  check your phpinfo()  output.